# 1D random walk with infinite crossings

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $x_i$ be a uniformly random real in $(-1,1)$. And let $f(x)$ be a strictly increasing positive and unbounded function.
Let $S_j(f)=x_0/f(0)+x_1/f(1)+x_2/f(2)+\cdots+x_j/f(j)$

Does $S_j(f)$ converge for every $f$?

Is there an $f$ such that with probability 1, the partial sums $S_j$ change sign infinitely many times and $S_j$ converges?

Comment: You may find section 5 of this paper useful: http://www.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/RandomWalks.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both questions is **no**.

By [Kolmogorov's three series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), $S_j(f)$ will converge almost surely if and only if $\sum_j {1/f(j)^2}<\infty$.  This fails, for instance, if $f(j)=1+\sqrt{j}$.

If $S_j(f)$ converges, it can only change sign infinitely many times provided the limit is zero. If that were true, the equation $x_0=-f(0)\ [x_1/f(1)+x_2/f(2)+\cdots]$
would show that the random variable $x_0$ is independent of itself. 
But this is impossible for a non-constant random variable.

Comment: Can any sum of random variables converge to 0 with probability 1 ?

Comment: For a sum of *independent* random variables, it can only happen if the summands are constants (variance equal to zero).